# What IP does Tor run off

Tags: configuration, anonymity

This is a very basic question, but I am very very new with proxies and Tor, I know very little about them which is kind of sad, and I'd really like to learn. My questions are:

- What IP do I run Tor off of?
- What port does Tor run on?

Sorry for being so noob at this..

Comment: What do you mean by *"What IP do I run Tor off of?"*? Are you asking which IP is Tor using? Are you talking about the Tor browser?

Answer (score 1):

TOR runs (the service, not bundle) runs on localhost on port 9050 by default.

So the IP would be `127.0.0.1` and the port `9050`.

Answer (score 0):

> - What IP do I run Tor off of?

Tor runs on your localhost which usually means `127.0.0.1`.

> - What port does Tor run on?

The port depends on what variant of Tor you're using:

- The most common way is to use the Tor Browser Bundle. Tor is configured to use port `9150`.
- If you're using Tor on a GNU/Linux box or have downloaded the Tor software as a standalone version, it will use port `9050`.
- Furthermore there is software like [Ricochet](https://ricochet.im/), which comes with a Tor binary. This Tor version might use another Tor port.